# How to alter python's json encoder to convert NaN to None

Tags: python, jsonencoder

Say I have this (all this is Python 3.11 in case that matters):

```
not_a_number = float("NaN")  # this actually comes from somewhere else
json.encode([not_a_number])
```

The output is an (invalid) JSON literal `NaN`. I've been trying to create an JSONEncoder subclass that would use `math.isnan()` to determine if the value is a `NaN` and output `None` instead.

I first tried subclassing JSONEncoder and doing it in `default()`, which I found later isn't called for things like float. I then found a recommendation to override the `encode()` method instead, so I tried this:

```
class NanEncoder(json.JSONEncoder):
    def encode(self, obj):
        if isinstance(obj, float):
            if math.isnan(obj):
                return None
        return super(NanEncoder, self).encode(obj)
```

This works:

```
>>> json.dumps(not_a_number, cls=NanEncoder)
>>> json_string = json.dumps(not_a_number, cls=NanEncoder)
>>> print(json_string)
None
```

Cool, I think I've got it. BUT, this does not work:

```
not_a_number_list = [not_a_number]
print(not_a_number_list)
[nan]
json_string = json.dumps(not_a_number_list, cls=NanEncoder)
print(json_string)
[NaN]
```

So, as I see in the python docs, maybe I need to call the encode method slightly differently, so I try that:

```
json_string = NanEncoder().encode(not_a_number_list)
print(json_string)
[NaN]
```

Alas, no difference.

So, here's my question: is it possible to create a JSONEncoder subclass that will find instances of the float that is `NaN` in Python and output `None` instead? Or am I relegated to do a search/replace on the string `NaN` with `null` in the output JSON (which, theoretically anyway, could alter data I don't want to)? Fixing the input dictionary is not a great option because the dict that the values are in is quite large and it's construction is not under my control (so I can't stop `NaN` from getting in there in the first place).

Comment: Your `encode()` should handle JSON encoding according to the [JSON specification](https://www.json.org/json-en.html) but all it does at the moment is encode only `if isinstance(obj, float)`. How about `if isinstance(obj, list)`, `if isinstance(obj, str)`, `if isinstance(obj, dict)`, `if isinstance(obj, bool)`, `if isinstance(obj, None)`. Trust me if [Python’s JSON library did as simple a job as you did, it wouldn’t be such a hit](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/034bb70aaad5622bd53bad21595b18b8f4407984/Lib/json/encoder.py#L183).

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about easy solution to replace `NaN` with custom values (other than replace `NaN`s in original object).

On top of that, `json` module doesn't make it easy to monkeypatch the inner workings: https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/034bb70aaad5622bd53bad21595b18b8f4407984/Lib/json/encoder.py#L224

But you can try:

```py
import json


def custom_make_iterencode(*args, **kwargs):
    def floatstr(
        o,
        allow_nan=True,
        _repr=float.__repr__,
        _inf=float("inf"),
        _neginf=float("-inf"),
    ):
        if o != o:
            text = "None"  # <--- Here is the actuall NaN replacement!
        elif o == _inf:
            text = "Infinity"
        elif o == _neginf:
            text = "-Infinity"
        else:
            return _repr(o)

        if not allow_nan:
            raise ValueError(
                "Out of range float values are not JSON compliant: " + repr(o)
            )

        return text

    return orig_make_iterencode(
        {},  # markers
        json.encoder.JSONEncoder.default,
        json.encoder.py_encode_basestring_ascii,
        None,  # indent
        floatstr,
        json.encoder.JSONEncoder.key_separator,
        json.encoder.JSONEncoder.item_separator,
        False,  # sort_keys
        False,  # skip_keys
        False,  # _one_shot
    )


orig_make_iterencode = json.encoder._make_iterencode

# https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/034bb70aaad5622bd53bad21595b18b8f4407984/Lib/json/encoder.py#L247
json.encoder._make_iterencode = custom_make_iterencode
json.encoder.c_make_encoder = None # <-- pretend we don't have C version of the function


# finally you can do:

print(json.dumps(float("nan")))
print(json.dumps([float("nan")]))

# don't forget to set the `json.encoder._make_iterencode` and `json.encoder.c_make_encoder` back!
```

Prints:

```py
None
[None]
```

Comment: As you can see from https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/034bb70aaad5622bd53bad21595b18b8f4407984/Lib/json/encoder.py#L247 on, `_make_iterencode` and `c_make_encoder` expect slightly different parameters, so it should be `json.encoder.c_make_encoder = None` instead.

Comment: @MichaelButscher Yup, actually, setting `json.encoder.c_make_encoder` to `None` is better (Now I just return python function, not the C-one)